# ¿Cómo puedo "estirar" mi scrollbar manualmente sin usar .pack() ni grid para ajustarlos a un widget Text?

Tags: python, tkinter, scroll, grid

```
# LIBRERIAS
from tkinter import *
import requests
import json

# EVENTO SALIR APP CON TECLA -ESC-
def close(event):
    root.withdraw() # if you want to bring it back
    sys.exit() # if you want to exit the entire thing

def Llama_Api():
    url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
    payload = {'nombre':'Antonio', 'curso':'python', 'nivel':'intermedio'}

    response = requests.post (url, json=payload)
    BOX.delete('1.0', END)                          #borrar todo el cuadro de texto
    BOX.insert(END, response.url + "\n\n")

    if response.status_code == 200:
        BOX.insert(END, response.content)


# ******************************************************* Script Principal ********************************************************
if __name__=="__main__":

#ESTADOS INICIALES
    AnchoFrame = 400                                         #parametro de ancho del frame
    AltoFrame  = 400    

# INTERFAZ GRÁFICA
    root = Tk()
    ox = root.winfo_screenwidth()/2
    oy = root.winfo_screenheight()/2

    root.geometry("=%dx%d+%d+%d" % (AnchoFrame, AltoFrame, ox -200, oy-250) )
    root.overrideredirect(1)                                #sacarle los bordes a la ventana                                                                                    #sin bordes
    root.title("Ejemplo API")                   #titulo
    root.resizable(False,False)                             #no puede cambiar de tamaño
    root.config(bd=0)                                       #grosot borde
    root.config(relief="flat", bg="black", borderwidth = 0)             #stilo borde

    miFrame=Frame(root, width=AnchoFrame, height=AltoFrame) #tamaño del frame
    miFrame.config(relief="flat", bg="grey38")          #stilo de frame
    miFrame.pack()                                          #empaquetado del frame

# Variables

#  LINEA DE SEPARACIÓN DECORATIVA
    Label_Separador_1 = Label(miFrame, text="__________________________________________________", font=("Helvetica",10), fg="grey68", bg="grey38")  #titulo ventana
    Label_Separador_1.place(x=20, y=20) 

# LABEL Titulos
    Label_Titulo = Label(miFrame, text="Python ", font=("Vivaldi",20), fg="grey68", bg="grey38")    #titulo ventana
    Label_Titulo.place(x=160, y=18) 

# BOTON AUX
    BOTON_AUX = Button(text="Consultar API", command=lambda:Llama_Api(), width=20, height=2, relief=FLAT, fg="grey92",bg="deepskyblue2")
    BOTON_AUX.place(x=210,y=340)

# BOTON SALIR
    BOTON_SALIR = Button(text="Salir",command=lambda:root.destroy(), width=20, height=2, relief=FLAT, fg="grey92",bg="deepskyblue2")
    BOTON_SALIR.place(x=40,y=340)

#  TEXTO
    BOX = Text(miFrame)
    scroll = Scrollbar(miFrame, command=BOX.yview, width=14)
    #scroll.grid(row=50, column=20, sticky="nsew")
    scroll.place(x=373,y=60)
    BOX.place(x=10, y=60, width=380, height=260)    
    BOX.config(bg="grey42", border=3, fg="grey92", state="normal", relief=FLAT, yscrollcommand=scroll.set)

# EVENTO ESC    
    root.bind('<Escape>', close) #EVENTO DE LA TECLA ESC

# MAINLOOP  
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

La clave está en no posicionar la barra de forma absoluta, sino posicionarla de forma relativa al widget `Text` y hacer que su altura dependa de la del `Text`.

Para ello `place` dispone del argumento `in_` que permite especificar el widget que se toma como base para calcular la posición y tamaño relativo. Después solo tenemos que usar `relheight=1` para que el tamaño de la misma sea siempre el mismo que el del widget `Text`.

Dejo un ejemplo basado en tu código pero simplificado:

```
import tkinter as tk



TEXTO = "Hola Stack Overflow en Español\n" * 30
ANCHO_FRAME = 400
ALTO_FRAME = 400    

root = tk.Tk()
ox = root.winfo_screenwidth() // 2
oy = root.winfo_screenheight() // 2

root.geometry("={}x{}+{}+{}".format(ANCHO_FRAME, ALTO_FRAME, ox - 200, oy - 250))
root.resizable(False, False)
root.config(bd=0)
root.config(relief="flat", bg="black", borderwidth=0)

frame = tk.Frame(root, width=ANCHO_FRAME, height=ALTO_FRAME)
frame.config(relief="flat", bg="grey38")
frame.pack()

box = tk.Text(frame)
scroll = tk.Scrollbar(frame, command=box.yview, width=14)
scroll.place(in_=box, relx=1, relheight=1, bordermode="outside")
box.place(x=10, y=60, width=366, height=270)    
box.config(bg="grey42", border=3, fg="grey92", state="normal",
           relief=tk.FLAT, yscrollcommand=scroll.set
           )

box.insert(tk.END, TEXTO)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]